# Injection between ordinals $\alpha \hookrightarrow \beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> Let $\alpha,\beta$ be ordinals.
>
> Suppose that there is an order embedding $f: \alpha\hookrightarrow\beta$.
>
> Show $\alpha \le \beta$, i.e. $\alpha\subset \beta$.

**Try 1**

There are two possibilities: $\alpha\subset \beta$ or $\beta\subset\alpha$. In the first case, we are done. In the second case, we can consider the composition $\beta\hookrightarrow \alpha \overset{f}{\hookrightarrow}\beta$ were the first arrow is the obvious inclusion map. This would produce an embedding from $\beta$ to itself, but it need not be surjective, so it doesn't seem useful.

**Try 2**

I also tried to fix $\alpha$ and proceed by transfinite induction on $\beta$, but got stuck. For instance, if I assume

$$\alpha\hookrightarrow \beta \implies \alpha\subset\beta$$

and take an embedding $f:\alpha\hookrightarrow S(\beta)=\beta\cup\{\beta\}$, we can distinguish two cases: $\beta\not\in f(\alpha)$ or $\beta\in f(\alpha)$. In the first case, it follows that actually $f:\alpha\hookrightarrow\beta$, so we can apply the induction hypothesis. I don't see how to proceed with the other case.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The map $\beta\hookrightarrow \alpha \overset{f}{\hookrightarrow}\beta$ is extremely useful: if it existed, and $\beta<\alpha$, there would be an order-embedding from $\beta$ to a proper subset of $\beta$. Prove by induction on $\beta$ that this is impossible.